# Salesforce Trigger to Count the Contact Roles on an Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I am checking [this link](http://www.oyecode.com/2012/01/salesforce-trigger-to-count-contact.html) and trying to use the below snippet:

```
/******************************************************************
        *Count Contact_Role_Count Field through map size 
        *****************************************************************/

List<OpportunityContactRole> oContactRoles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>(contactRoleMap.get(oppy.id));    

if(oContactRoles!=NULL && !oContactRoles.isempty()){ 
    oppy.ContactRoleCount__c = oContactRoles.size();                                                                                      //return the map size
}
```

In this i am unable to compile it as it is giving me an error

> `oppy` variable undefined.

Can anyone help me out how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might be better served by [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Comment: I've always used this package. (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000025Vs1EAE) Part of the trigger counts the number of contact roles and stores it on the oppty. Just be sure to deactivate the validation rules in the package if you don't want to enforce the assignment of a primary contact role! It's also unmanaged, so you can rip their code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code from the link you provided, it seems you have to create a for loop which loops through the opportunities in the trigger.

```
for(Opportunity oppy : Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap.values()) {
    //your code here
}
```

Either way, the code is incomplete on the blog post. You might want to reach out to the author.